# error listen EADDRINUSE: address already in use :::19000

Tags: node.js, react-native

When Starting my app this error is coming somebody please help
Getting this error[node js][1]
error listen EADDRINUSE: address already in use :::19000.
Developer tools running on http://localhost:19002
Opening developer tools in the browser...
› Opening exp://192.168.43.102:80 on Pixel_4_API_30
Starting Metro Bundler`enter code here`
error listen EADDRINUSE: address already in use :::19000.

```
Error: listen EADDRINUSE: address already in use :::19000
    at Server.setupListenHandle [as _listen2] (net.js:1320:16)
    at listenInCluster (net.js:1368:12)
    at Server.listen (net.js:1454:7)
    at C:\Users\Aman\a\pnd\node_modules\metro\src\index.js:240:20
    at new Promise (<anonymous>)
    at Object.<anonymous> (C:\Users\Aman\a\pnd\node_modules\metro\src\index.js:239:14)
    at Generator.next (<anonymous>)
    at asyncGeneratorStep (C:\Users\Aman\a\pnd\node_modules\metro\src\index.js:46:24)
    at _next (C:\Users\Aman\a\pnd\node_modules\metro\src\index.js:66:9)
Metro Bundler process exited with code 1
Error: Metro Bundler process exited with code 1
    at ChildProcess.<anonymous> (C:\Users\Aman\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\expo-cli\node_modules\xdl\src\start\startLegacyReactNativeServerAsync.ts:271:16)
    at Object.onceWrapper (events.js:482:26)
    at ChildProcess.emit (events.js:375:28)
    at Process.ChildProcess._handle.onexit (internal/child_process.js:277:12)
npm ERR! code ELIFECYCLE
npm ERR! errno 1
npm ERR! @ start: `expo start`
npm ERR! Exit status 1
npm ERR!
npm ERR! Failed at the @ start script.
npm ERR! This is probably not a problem with npm. There is likely additional logging output above.

npm ERR! A complete log of this run can be found in:
npm ERR!     C:\Users\Aman\AppData\Roaming\npm-cache\_logs\2021-07-23T09_22_23_399Z-debug.log



  [1]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/xxcZZ.png
```

Answer (score 2):

This error says some other process already uses that port 1900.

**For Windows users (case in question):**
See [answer by Francesco Clementi](https://stackoverflow.com/a/68497407/1808052).

**For Linux users:**
Use `netstat` (part of `net-tools` package) to find out which processes use it:

```
netstat -tulpn | fgrep 1900
```

Then use:

```
ps -aux | fgrep <process name>
```

to figure out the process ID. Once you have process ID you can stop that process with:

```
kill -9 <ID>
```

**Warning: this effectively kills the process holding that port, which may result in data corruption or loss, that is managed by that process. Proceed with care.**

Answer (score 1):

You have two solution.

first:

kill the process using that port with

> netstat -ano | findstr :19000

> taskkill /PID  /F

the first command will give you a list of processes running on that port, then you need to get the PID and replace it on the second command.

second:

reboot your computer.